# How to divide an image with specific dimensions using linear gradient? Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to implement something similar to Sample1 image. But the result I got is Sample2 image. Can anyone please help me with these

[Sample1New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D91t0.jpg)

[Sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuIw6.jpg)

Here is the code I have tried

```
   public void Draw(Canvas canvas)
{
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0,0,bitmap.Width,bitmap.Height,new int[]{CSSColor, PrevColor},new float[] { 0.5f, 0.5f },Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  matrix.SetRotate(45,bitmap.Width/2,bitmap.Height/2);
  shader.SetLocalMatrix(matrix);
  paint.SetShader(shader);
  canvas.DrawRect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, paint);
}
```

Comment: Increase the rotation degree to 70 on set rotate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7462031/g-hakim Hi, Thanks for your answer.But sorry It din't help me.I have edited my sample1 image. can you please check that and help me. Thanks in Advance!!